# Ransomware public key: can I find the respective private key?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, file-encryption, decryption, ransomware

I got a ransomware called StopDjvu. On my PC, I have found the public key that is used by the malware (maybe RSA hardcoded).

Is it possible to extract the private key from the public key?

Answer (score 2):

No.  If it were possible to derive the private key from the public key, then this would break asymmetric encryption.   This would make it possible to break the encryption for https, VPNs, SSH, Signal, cryptocurrencies, and much more.

As a thought experiment, take a look at this bitcoin address:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/12tkqA9xSoowkzoERHMWNKsTey55YEBqkv

As you can see, this address has ~28,000 bitcoins associated with it.  At today's exchange rate, that's almost half a billion USD.  The public key is in the clear.  If it were possible to derive the private key from the public key, someone would have done it by now and used the private key to steal all the bitcoins from this address.  But, to date, this has never happened.  So, think of bitcoin as a massive bug bounty on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, things like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYCzu04ftaY or this article https://0day.work/how-i-recovered-your-private-key-or-why-small-keys-are-bad/ are useless for my case?

Comment: No, for the reasons stated by Spyros.  See what I added to my answer above.

Comment: Actually a bitcoin address is a _hash_ of (a defined representation of) the public key; to reverse an address you must both reverse the hash _and_ the (resulting) public key, both of which are impossible. _If_ there had been a payment _from_ this address (more exactly a spend of any TXO(s) for the address) _that_ txn's script would have exposed the public key (but not the private key).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for pointing this out.  I meant to choose an address that had a payment from the address for the purpose of this example, but inexplicably chose this one that doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Public key cryptography uses mathematical constructs that makes it really difficult (practically impossible) to find a private key once you know the public key.

So, the answer is no.

Comment: So, things like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYCzu04ftaY or this article https://0day.work/how-i-recovered-your-private-key-or-why-small-keys-are-bad/ are useless for my case?

Comment: Yes. Both are specially crafted examples for demonstration purposes only. The prerequisites of the examples do not apply in the real world.